# Use window builder jframe in a different class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I am trying to use a gui i built with window builder in eclipse using jframe. I have tried to call the method Ftwo(); in my main method and i imported the class but it does not recognize the method thanks
    package com.cameron.main;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Ftwo extends JFrame {



    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Ftwo frame = new Ftwo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Ftwo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

}
```

Comment: `public Ftwo()` is a constructor.

Comment: @ck1 i understand but how do i put it into the main method

Comment: It looks like you're trying to delve into complex Java, such as creating and running a GUI, before you've studied and understood basic Java, and this is  backwards and putting the proverbial cart before the horse. You're far better off studying and learning the basics first, and I urge you to do just that -- get a decent intro to Java book and study it and work out its problems. Build a knowledge foundation before trying to build a sky scraper.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `MyApp` is in the same Java package, just instantiate a new `Ftwo` instance and set it visible.  For example:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ftwo ftwo = new Ftwo();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> ftwo.setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: how would i add parameters to the method each time to for example change what the text says instead of making a new gui every time

Comment: Add a `String` parameter to the constructor that is used to set the text on a `JLabel` in `Ftwo`.  E.g. `public Ftwo(String text)`.

Comment: Another option: add a public setter on `Ftwo` that sets the text on a `JLabel`.  E.g. `ftwo.setText("Some text!");`

Comment: how would i add multiple guis with different text